# Some files with .PDF extensions are unreadable

Tags: oracle, pdf, internet-explorer, firefox

Some documents with filenames ending with .PDF(in caps), when clicked on their hyperlinks, are opening in the browser without asking for open with/save as options. But the file is opened in an incorrect format. The content is not understandable at all after someone reads it. There is an entry for each of these files in DB table. The DB is Oracle 10 G. Don't know whether this is application issue or DB issue or PDF add on the issue on the browser. The file as it is shown on the browsers IE and Chrome is given below. The problem is the same for IE and chrome. If someone can help, then it will be very much appreciated.

```
%PDF-1.1
1 0 obj
<<
/Creator (Developer 2000)
/CreatorDate (Wed Apr 19  2017)
/Author (Oracle Reports)
/Producer (Oracle PDF driver)
/Title (XXX DEBIT_XXXXX.PDF)
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Length 6 0 R>>
stream
q 175.72 0 0 40.92 393.60 10.04 cm /im220 Do Q
q 93.76 0 0 51.08 32.16 807.64 cm /im268 Do Q
q 171.88 0 0 118.48 34.40 6.00 cm /im315 Do Q
0.00 w
0 J
0 j
33.64 235.32 550.60 558.08 re S
q
159.80 776.04 185.04 17.36 re W n
BT
204.00 778.64 TD
/F0 16.00 Tf
(DEBIT NOTE) Tj
```

Comment: How do you store the PDF file into the Oracle database? using byte array or just store the file path? When click the hyperlink, what action are you will taking? can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Besides, which version of IE browser version are you using?

Comment: Can you share a complete example PDF? Version 1.1 of PDF is the earliest version of that format and might differ much from what PDF processors nowadays expect.

Answer (score 0):

What you have shared appears to be a partial PDF file, without the **rest** of the file present it's bound to cause problems in browsers (which generally are a poor substitute for a PDF viewer).

Comment: Hi, It is not possible to share the entire content of the pdf as this will exceed the limit of characters here by a huge margin. But one fact I should tell that when I download the file from server path using winscp and save it in my PC. After that I can open it and it is perfectly readable. But when someone clicks the hyperlink in the application to open the pdf, then file is opened in a new tab and it is not understandable at all.